# Is there a way to record the production server traffic and replay the same in stage environment using AWS traffic mirror feature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have an aws setup for testing we want to capture the traffic from live environment and play the same in the test environment, we tried with the AWS traffic mirror however we did not achieve the end goal need suggestion on this can be achieved through **AWS traffic mirror**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The question is very broad and leaves a lot to assume, so I'd recommend to read and follow the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.  You need to be very specific to get a reasonable answer. `we tried... and did not achieve.. ` is really not giving out a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "did not achieve the end goal"? How did it not meet your goal? Is the traffic coming from a single server? When you say "capture and play", are you wanting to record the traffic and play it back later, or are you wanting to play it as soon as it is captured? Please Edit your question to add these details.

Comment: With AWS Traffic Mirroring you should be able to mirror traffic you want and post it to the target. What can be done with mirrored traffic is up to you. Yes, I would like to know how did you "not achieve the end goal?"